# Script counting more than it was expected

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a large tsv file which I need to get "junction_aa" and "v_call" columns and sum how many times a junction_aa apears with the same v_call

example:

| junction_aa | v_call |
| --- | --- |
| CARLVMATFPGLDYW | IGHV5-51*01 |
| CARLVMATFPGLDYW | IGHV5-51*01 |
| CARLVMATFPGLDYW | IGLV1-47*02 |
| CHQYHNWPPWTF | IGHV5-51*01 |
| CHQYHNWPPWTF | IGHV5-51*01 |
| CHQYHNWPPWTF | IGLV1-47*02 |

then:

| junction_aa | v_call | contagem |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CARLVMATFPGLDYW | IGHV5-51*01 | 2 |
| CARLVMATFPGLDYW | IGLV1-47*02 | 1 |
| CHQYHNWPPWTF | IGHV5-51*01 | 2 |
| CHQYHNWPPWTF | IGLV1-47*02 | 1 |

I tried to write a code in Python to this, with the help from chat gpt I reached this result:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

argvs = sys.argv
path = argvs[1]
output = argvs[2]

tabela = pd.read_csv(path, sep='\t')

expanded_data = [(j_aa, v_call) for j_aa, v_calls in tabela[['junction_aa', 'v_call']].values for v_call in v_calls.split(',')]

expanded_df = pd.DataFrame(expanded_data, columns=['junction_aa', 'v_call'])

counter = expanded_df.groupby(['junction_aa', 'v_call']).size().reset_index(name='contagem')

counter.to_csv(output, sep='\t', index=False)
```

It has been about 2 months since I did this, but today selecting the lines from the tables, I discovered that the numbers didn't add up

In the original table it has by example 29081 lines (each line has only one v_call and only one junction_aa), but in the file created by the script, summing all the numbers that it counted, it has 35487 items

What was expected was to the sum get 29081 items too

[image: original table]

[image: after script table]

Using dynamic table it reaches the sum that is expected, but I want that the similars junction_aa don't be agroupped, like in the example, all separated
[image: sum expected]

I don't know if there is a way that I can put an example file here, but I'll share a google drive link to a file before and after the script:
[before](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v0-MvshCQ56XPiOxmVJ3tGHMeyQkzmbn/view?usp=sharing)
[after](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CA2D86SnhKQ2HXQuNdf32G5si0zEDY_3/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: If you're splitting the `v_calls` value from the original table then you should expect to get a higher count in the output

Comment: The posted tsv file has column `junction`, but the code is looking for `junction_aa`.  Which is it?

Comment: junction_aa, sorry

Comment: but how can I make it work correctly without splitting? sorry I'm not so studied in python

Comment: It was from another file, I gave that because it was smaller, but I'll correct the number in the post

Comment: If the original table has `CARLVMATFPGLDYW\tIGHV5-51*01,IGLV1-47*02` that will be 1 row in the original table, but the count will be 2 in the result. So a higher count is expected. Why do you think that's wrong?

Comment: What result are you expecting instead?

Comment: I added in the post some explanation, hope that now is more clarifying

Comment: Hi. If you like, a couple advice to possibly improve redability and chances of getting answers. TSV reading and writing are not in question -they work fine, right? So, [mre]: trim this post down to dataframe before / after / expected + the processing part of the code? That way, no need to use images since dataframe samples may be displayed as text inside the post.

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample input, which I call **input-sample.tsv**:

```
| junction_aa     | v_call      |
|-----------------|-------------|
| CARLVMATFPGLDYW | IGHV5-51*01 |
| CARLVMATFPGLDYW | IGHV5-51*01 |
| CARLVMATFPGLDYW | IGLV1-47*02 |
| CHQYHNWPPWTF    | IGHV5-51*01 |
| CHQYHNWPPWTF    | IGHV5-51*01 |
| CHQYHNWPPWTF    | IGLV1-47*02 |
```

And the first 10 rows of the TSV you shared, **input-small.tsv**:

```
| sequence_id               | junction_aa            | v_call      |
|---------------------------|------------------------|-------------|
| 6d8cd903-032b-4994-bc8... | CARLVMATFPGLDYW        | IGHV5-51*01 |
| 8eb08ca9-3023-4976-9a3... | CARLIGFCSGTSCYGDRW     | IGHV5-51*01 |
| 3383e584-c856-41bf-b95... | CARHQLGILRHYYYMDVW     | IGHV5-51*01 |
| c9a0c6da-ebea-4894-ae0... | CARPGVAAGTPDYWGYYGMDVW | IGHV5-51*01 |
| f0982a63-0fe8-4a22-8b3... | CGTWDDSLNGQVF          | IGLV1-44*01 |
| b9b30181-c3a0-4e04-ae4... | CQQYGDSPLTF            | IGKV3-11*01 |
| 75baf5b5-e955-496d-a59... | CAAWDDSLNAWVF          | IGLV1-47*02 |
| e1fe0c58-6d7e-472f-857... | CVLYIGSGIWVF           | IGLV8-61*01 |
| 8ab5858f-4aae-4c64-87f... | CLQHNSYPHTF            | IGKV1-17*01 |
| 6059d93f-c975-4fea-bc9... | CASYAGASSWVF           | IGLV2-11*01 |
```

I get the following results...

```
| junction_aa     | v_call      | contagem |
|-----------------|-------------|----------|
| CARLVMATFPGLDYW | IGHV5-51*01 | 2        |
| CARLVMATFPGLDYW | IGLV1-47*02 | 1        |
| CHQYHNWPPWTF    | IGHV5-51*01 | 2        |
| CHQYHNWPPWTF    | IGLV1-47*02 | 1        |
```

and...

```
| junction_aa            | v_call      | contagem |
|------------------------|-------------|----------|
| CARLVMATFPGLDYW        | IGHV5-51*01 | 1        |
| CARLIGFCSGTSCYGDRW     | IGHV5-51*01 | 1        |
| CARHQLGILRHYYYMDVW     | IGHV5-51*01 | 1        |
| CARPGVAAGTPDYWGYYGMDVW | IGHV5-51*01 | 1        |
| CGTWDDSLNGQVF          | IGLV1-44*01 | 1        |
| CQQYGDSPLTF            | IGKV3-11*01 | 1        |
| CAAWDDSLNAWVF          | IGLV1-47*02 | 1        |
| CVLYIGSGIWVF           | IGLV8-61*01 | 1        |
| CLQHNSYPHTF            | IGKV1-17*01 | 1        |
| CASYAGASSWVF           | IGLV2-11*01 | 1        |
```

with the following script (explained in sections)...

Since you don't know Python, any reason not learn?

Python's csv module can read and write CSV/TSV files.  Start by importing the csv module, and defining the input TSV filename and output counts filename:

```py
import csv

FNAME_IN = "input-sample.tsv"
FNAME_OUT = "output-sample.tsv"
```

Open the input file, and create a DictReader around that file, specifying the tab ("\t") as the delimiter.  Also, when using the csv module it's recommended to specify `newline=""` when opening the file:

```py
with open(FNAME_IN, newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter="\t")
    rows = list(reader)

print(rows)
```

The `rows` var is a list of dicts for each row.  The keys are the column names and values are each field's value, and looks like:

```py
[
    {"junction_aa": "CARLVMATFPGLDYW", "v_call": "IGHV5-51*01"},
    {"junction_aa": "CARLVMATFPGLDYW", "v_call": "IGHV5-51*01"},
    {"junction_aa": "CARLVMATFPGLDYW", "v_call": "IGLV1-47*02"},
    ...
]
```

Next you'll need to loop over the rows and count how many combinations of junction_aa and v_call you find.  Python has a Counter type which does just this (I've also included the type hints).  As you loop over the rows, call out the columns you care about by name and create a tuple out of them, called `key`.  You then pass the key to the counter and increment the count for that key by 1; if the key didn't already exist, the counter will add it:

```py
from collections import Counter
from typing import Counter  # omit if not available in your version of Python

c: Counter[tuple[str, str]] = Counter()

for row in rows:
    key = (row["junction_aa"], row["v_call"])
    c[key] += 1
```

You can get a glimpse of what the counter looks like when you're done looping and counting:

```py
print(c.most_common(3))
```

```py
[
    (("CARLVMATFPGLDYW", "IGHV5-51*01"), 2),
    (("CHQYHNWPPWTF",    "IGHV5-51*01"), 2),
    (("CARLVMATFPGLDYW", "IGLV1-47*02"), 1),
]
```

Finally:

- open your counts file for writing and create a csv writer around that file (specifying the tab delimiter if you need another TSV file)
- write out the first row with your header
- loop over all the keys and their counts, and write each to its own row; the `items()` method on the counter returns an interator of keys and counts, `[(("CARLVMATFPGLDYW", "IGHV5-51*01"), 2), (("CHQYHNWPPWTF", "IGHV5-51*01"), 2), ...]`, like you saw above:

```py
with open(FNAME_OUT, "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter="\t")

    writer.writerow(["junction_aa", "v_call", "contagem"])

    for key, count in c.items():
        junct_aa, vcall = key  # split the key tuple into individuals str vars
        writer.writerow([junct_aa, vcall, count])
```